Movie about a transfer student that befriends a working student who is good at piano and a star athlete?
I think this movie was made in late 90's or early 2000's.
As far as I can remember this Chinese student transfered to an American/English high school. In her first day there she was toured by this guy (American) who was a working student. He told her that they don't have a bell so she should keep her own time. Then she was assigned to a roommate who is a smoker. That night they had a party and she was bullied by her classmates and she was stripped off her blouse and she run to the woods crying. Then the guy (working student) helped her.
Then there was also a scene where she and the guy were talking on the rooftop and their classmates saw them and they thought they were a couple and in the morning they taught her about s*x.
Then there is another guy who is a good athlete and he eventually falls in love with her. There was a scene where the working student guy and the athlete were seatmates and they imagined they were fighting with swords. Then they helped her adjust to the school and she wasn't bullied anymore.
In the end they all became good friends. The working student also became a professional pianist.

Fakin' Da Funk (1997)? This movie is about a Chinese boy adopted by a black family that moves to LA. A second part of the story is the Chinese exchange student (Margaret Cho) that has experiences similar to what you mention. The movie is full of racial stereotypes. I would definitely classify it as a comedy.
Interesting fact: Margaret Cho is Korean, not Chinese.
http://www.nndb.com/films/719/000070509/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119097/

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details form the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
